Camera zoom in to 3D point in SceneKit scene
I would like to implement zoom functionality in my SceneKit game: when the user performs the pinch gesture on a point on the screen, the scene zooms in to make that point larger.
Until now I simply changed SCNCamera.focalLength, but this simply zooms in to the center of what is currently visible on screen. Is it somehow possible to implement the zoom functionality described above by perhaps interactively rotating the camera at the same time towards the pinched point? Is there a formula for this? I would like to avoid suddenly rotating the camera to face the pinched point when the pinch gesture begins and then zoom in while the pinch is in progress.

If you want to pinch into a specific point (the center of the pinch gesture for example), you need somehow to manage the Z-Distance. This can be ether a fixed distance or you do a hit-test on some scene content. Then you adjust the distance of the camera depending on the intensity of the pinch gesture. There are many ways, how you could implement this. All depends on your requirements. And there are other things to keep in mind i.Ex: Is you camera constrained (does it follow a character). There are plenty of possibilities. If you can describe me, how exactly you imagine, I can better help you.

The camera is not constrained. I was imagining that a zoom shouldn't modify the camera's position, so as not to distract the user by the sudden change in perspective.

well, sudden perspective changes are ugly. but you could transition the camera slowly. I did that once in a game. the result was very good. I was using positioning nodes, that are invisible, and the camera was constrained to some point in front of the character running around. when I started running, the camera moved away, and when I was stopping, the camera moved again closer to the character. when you work with constraints, use position and look-at constraints... the camera transitions were always very soft.

Thanks for the suggestion, but I think that's a different use case. Yours was more a stylistic choice, whereas in my case the user expects a specific result (a camera zoom and not a camera movement).
